# "Willst du der Schülerin helfen?" why dative case "der Schülerin" but not "die Schülerin"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

I saw this sentence and don't understand why *Schülerin* is dative but not accusative. *helfen* is transitive verb so the object must be direct object so why it is dative?

> Willst du der Schülerin helfen?

Comment: There is no term "direct object" (or "indirect object", for that matter) in respect to German grammar. I'm afraid but you should forget about English grammar (or whichever language's grammar your supposition was based on) altogether.

Comment: What does your dictionary say about helfen? http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=helfen&l=deen&in=&lf=de

Comment: Only in English the verb to help is transitive. But in other languages this  can be different.

Answer (score 4):

*Helfen* is not a transitive verb. The English verb *help* is, but transitivity is not a property preserved by translation of any language to any language. So is reflexivity and other properties. If you need to know the characterize a verb, you need to look for their properties in German.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few definitions and assumptions in your question that are going haywire and maybe causing the confusion you have.

**Direct/indirect objects**

While it is technically not *wrong* to speak of direct and indirect objects in German, it is not the usual practice. Neither dative nor accusative objects require any indirect attachment to the verb — much unlike in English or French, and therefore they could technically both be called direct objects. However, due to similarities with other European languages, *direct object* can be understood to mean *accusative object* while *indirect object* can mean *dative object*.

I would advise you to use the case names for German.

**Transitive verbs**

There are two definitions of transitive verbs out there. School grammar usually assumes a transitive verb immediately if and only if the verb has an accusative object which, if the sentence is transformed into the passive voice, becomes a subject.

Linguistically, a verb is called transitive if it has *two required arguments*, the first being the subject and the second being an object. So in the example sentence of *I help him* we have the verb *to help* and its two arguments *I* and *him*. If we leave out either argument, we get an invalid sentence proving both arguments are obligatory. The same is true for the sentence *Ich helfe dir*. This means that *helfen* also has two required arguments and can therefore be called *transitive*.

**Transitive verbs must have a direct object**

Using the school definition of transitivity and the assumption direct object = accusative this might be correct (a.k.a. I’m too lazy to go looking for a counterexample). Using the linguistic definition it is wrong for German if the same object assumption is made. It might work for English and French but different languages have different rules. (And if you want to remember just one thing from this post, remember the second half of that sentence.)

---

Concerning your example:
*Jemande**m** helfen* is a verb that requires a dative object and only a dative object. Using an accusative object for the verb is wrong, and in the passive voice the object remains dative.

> <strike>Da *werden Sie* geholfen.</strike> (quote from a TV advertising campaign)
>
> Da *wird Ihnen* geholfen.

*Helfen* can now be classified:

- by school grammar as an intransitive verb with an obligatory dative argument
- linguistically as a transitive verb that requires a nominative and a dative argument.

In neither case would *helfen* ever take accusative.

Comment: "If we leave out either argument, we get an invalid sentence proving both arguments are obligatory. The same is true for the sentence Ich helfe dir." - because "Ich helfe." is an invalid sentence? As a native speaker, that's news to me.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper ‘Ich helfe’ is a valid sentence if and only if **it is clear by context who or what you are helping.** Of course that context is often given, if somebody runs somewhere crying ‘ich helfe!’ ;)

Answer (score 1):

> *helfen* is transitive verb

No, it is not. And that is already the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Helfen* is always dative. It's just a rule. It's always *'Hilf mir!'* never *'Hilf mich.'* Just one of the things you have to learn with the language. Similar to the way it's always *'Sag mir'* but *'Frag mich.'* Doesn't make any sense, but that's the way it is.

Here's a good list of dative, German verbs.
http://german.about.com/library/verbs/blverb_dativ.htm

Comment: Well, "sagen" and "fragen" are not good examples. The confusion probably arouse because it was assumed that English direct object equals German accusative and English indirect object equals German dative. Now compare those two words between German & English: "Sag es mir - Say it to me." - "Frage mich - Ask me". Better example, for instance: "Thank you - Danke dir"

Comment: I think it's a great example.
In English, you would say, "Ask me a question." Ask [indirect object] a [direct object].
Or "Tell me a story." Tell [indirect object] a [direct object].
In both cases, in English, your question or statement are direct objects, which most English speakers would assume translate directly to German.

Comment: Yeah, if you translate that sentence with "ask" word-for-word, you happen to have a perfect German sentence. Thus, I don't think it's a good example. – "To tell" (in German "erzählen") is a good example. Because there's a English direct objects versus a German dative. Unfortunately, you chose "sagen" in your answer, which is not a good example as it's an indirect object in English ("Say it *to me*").

Comment: Sag IHM dass er mich anrufen soll.
Frag IHN warum er mich nicht anrufen hat.

It's the same whether you use sagen or erzählen because they will both act as transitive verbs as they would in English. Fragen is the word that doesn't act as expected. You are asking a person a question. The question is the direct object, the person is the indirect object. So, you would expect the person to whom you're posing the question to be dativ (Frag mir, Frag ihm) but that isn't the case. The same as with helfen. So, no, if you translated the "ask" question word for word, you would have Frag mir eine Frage.

Comment: correction: *angerufen

Comment: You wouldn't. "Ask a question to me" would be "Frage mir eine Frage."

Comment: The 'to' is implied in the sentence "Ask me a question." It is understood that "me" isn't the thing which is being posed as a question (direct object), but rather the person the question is being posed TO (indirect object). The same way "Tell me a story" and "Tell a story to me" are saying the same thing. The "to" is understood in the first sentence.

Comment: I disagree. Anyway, I'm getting tired of discussing this. I was just saying that the two verbs are not good examples. Not sure why we're talking about this now. I'm out.

Comment: In English, word order normally dictates direct and indirect object in a sentence. [Verb] [indirect object] [direct object]. "Throw me the ball." If you break that pattern, you need a word like 'to' to clarify. "Throw the ball to me." German, on the other hand, uses article case. "Wirf mir den Ball" and "Wirf den Ball mir" will both be understood in the same way regardless of the word order.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which is your native language?

Comment: In German (that's my native language), you add "zu", too. "Wirf den Ball zu mir". — Anyway, that was never my point. Neither word order nor adding "to" (or "zu", respectively"). It was about the false assumption (that learners often do) that you could compare German & English grammar. And in this respect, I'm afraid, your examples are still not good, because they are like "accusative == direct object, dative == indirect object", which often is the case, but not always. Anyway....

Comment: I'm pretty sure in your native language, the 'zu' is optional and not necessary for understanding of what is being thrown (because of 'mir' and 'den'). Not saying it wouldn't commonly be used, but it's not necessary. Without it, you completely understand what is being thrown. In English, without the 'to' the sentence makes no sense at all. It's one of the major differences between the two languages. Point being, the same way a native English speaker would expect "Hilf mich," we would also expect "Frag mir" which is what's causing OP's confusion. But, yeah, feel free to disagree.

Comment: @TroyFrazier: Both "Wirf mir den Ball." and "Wirf den Ball mir." are incomplete in German, as the verb "werfen" normally does not work with a dative object without a preposition. So, no, "zu" is *not* optional. You are right about the aspect that with "mir", it is indeed not necessary to understand what is being thrown. However, the "zu" is necessary to understand what the meaning of "mir" is with respect to the described action. And when it's "euch" rather than "mir", you also need the "zu" to recognize what is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

> '*helfen*' is a transitive verb

In ***German*** '*helfen*' is not a transitive verb!

In ***English*** or all ***Romance*** languages it is...

Comment: @Gerhard: I am so reluctant to doing that, because romance also means 'Romanze', but thanks anyhow...