# Why "ihrem Freund helfen" and not "ihren Freund helfen"?

Tags: english-to-german, grammatical-case, dative

> Laura will ihrem Freund beim Kochen helfen.

In this sentence *ihre**m*** is used instead of *ihre**n***. Why is that? There is no dative preposition here.

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25284/willst-du-der-sch%c3%bclerin-helfen-why-dative-case-der-sch%c3%bclerin-but-not-die-s, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/65288/in-the-sentence-ich-begegnete-einem-alten-freund-in-berlin-why-the-dative-ein and possibly others.

Answer (score 6):

Not only prepositions but also verbs determine which case to use in German.

While most of the verbs in German require accusative case, there are several verbs that require dative case and even some that require genitive case.

*Helfen* is one of the verbs that require dative case.

If you look up a verb in [dwds.de](https://www.dwds.de/wb/helfen) you will find a lot of example sentences. That might help you to figure out which case to use with a verb.

Comment: So if I use a dative verb the case will always be dative then?

Comment: In a simple sentence yes. There might be construction (e.g. with infinitive and *zu*) where other rules apply. But normally: yes.

Comment: Dative verbs are covered in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_verbs#Dative_verbs), though I'm not a fan of how they explain it. Any good grammar should cover this topic as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.